# Unable to Deploy Azure Python Function as Zip

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions

I would be very grateful for some assistance with this issue.

I have an Azure Function App and I simply wish to deploy a function to it using a .zip. I have been using the Powershell command:

```
Publish-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName <my-rg-name> -Name test-linux-func-app-98962 -ArchivePath myfunc.zip
```

I get a confirmation and to all intents and purposes it deploys; the response included a 'state' property which is set to 'running'.

Inside that myfunc.zip is the following:

- `__init__.py`
- function.json
- host.json
- requirements.txt

The function.json contains:

```json
{
    "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
    "bindings": [
        {
            "type": "httpTrigger",
            "direction": "in",
            "name": "req",
            "methods": [
                "get",
                "post"
            ],
            "route": "hitme",
            "authLevel": "anonymous"
        },
        {
            "type": "http",
            "direction": "out",
            "name": "$return"
        }
    ]
}
```

The host.json is:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensionBundle": {
        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
        "version": "[2.6.1, 3.0.0)"
    },
    "extensions": {
        "http": {
            "routePrefix": ""
        }
    }
}
```

The **init**.py contains a single main function which simply returns a 'hello world' string.

The requirements.txt includes a single dependency:

```
azure-functions==1.13.3
```

In the Function App itself I have the following configuration values in app settings (configuration):

```
ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD = true
SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT = false
WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = true
FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME = python
FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION = ~4
```

It simply will not deploy, but as far as I can see there are no errors being generated by Powershell. When I try to deploy using az cli I see a 202:

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g <my-rg-name> -n test-linux-func-app-98962 --src myfunc.zip

Getting scm site credentials for zip deployment
Starting zip deployment. This operation can take a while to complete ...
Deployment endpoint responded with status code 202
{
  "active": true,
  "author": "N/A",
  "author_email": "N/A",
  "complete": true,
  "deployer": "Push-Deployer",
....
```

However the function never every shows up in the /functions blade in the UI and when I hit the http url I never see anything except the Azure functions default web page. I'm out of ideas.. all I am trying to do is deploy a Python hello world from a .zip :-(

Would be very grateful if someone could tell me where I am messing this up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to Deploy Azure Python Function as Zip

I have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below and I have followed [Microsoft_document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/publish-azwebapp?view=azps-9.6.0):

Using Powershell:

```
Publish-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "v-rbojja" -Name "rithwik33" -ArchivePath "C:\Users\source\repos\emo.zip"
```

[image]

**In Portal:**

In portal you will not find in Functions blade, which you deployed as zip.

You can see/find functions deployed  in App Service Editor as below:

[image]

Then:

[image]

Using Azure cli and Followed [Microsoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/deployment?view=azure-cli-latest):

```
$s="C:\Users\source\repos\emo.zip"
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g "bojja" -n "rithwik2123"  --src $s
```

[image]

In Portal:

In portal you will not find in Functions blade which you deployed as zip you can see in App Service Editor as below:

[image]

[image]

You can also run like below:

[image]

This is expected behavior as you are deploying zip function.